# What native PHP methods can I reliably use to compress/uncompress data for sending via http?

Tags: php, http

I need to send a fairly large chunk of data from one server (PHP 5.3) to thousands of different servers running all sorts of different PHP versions, web servers, modules and operating systems (all PHP 4.3+).

The data I am sending is formatted text with lots of white space etc. So I would like to compress it before sending and uncompress it at the end point.

Is there a native PHP solution that will allow me to do this?

If not, what would be the solution supported by the most end points?

It does not necessarily have to compress the data, but prepare it for transport via HTTP. Does urlencode() preserve line breaks?

Comment: have you tried to $.trim with jquery before it does actually goes back to the server?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.compression.php

Comment: for just post data just let the servers handle it themselves assuming they have gzip http enabled.  There's not much to gain from creating an archive before hand then transmitting the archive across.

Comment: It's not PHP, but I'd recommend rsync.

Comment: @LeviMorrison Don't forget about bittorrent =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [gzcompress](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzcompress.php) and [gzuncompress](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzuncompress.php) functions, this functions were available since PHP 4.0.1

Comment: But do they not require that the gzip library is installed? How reliable is that?

Comment: As far as I know, this two functions did not require any external library.